# Webpack dynamic require with loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to import a `.svg` file and replace some text in it during import using a loader.

```
import { PARKING_PIN_COLOR } from "styles/colors"

var path = "multiple-replace?COLOR=" + PARKING_PIN_COLOR + "!images/"
const PinParkingLotActive = require(path + "pin-parking-lot-active.svg")
```

However this code gives me this output in the webdev server:
`[1292] ./src/map/internal/components ^.*pin\-parking\-lot\-active\.svg$ 160 bytes {0} [built]`

And of course during runtime the file cannot be found.

```
Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:11347:2), <anonymous>:112:71)
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:11347:2), <anonymous>:112:149)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:11347:2), <anonymous>:411:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:11347:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:556:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:87:20)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:11320:2), <anonymous>:16:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:11320:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:556:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:4000/bundle.js:87:20)
```

Are such constellations not supported?